# "Invalid Binary" in iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes

I just tried submitted my App into iTunes, after several steps, I thought it was finally uploaded through Application Loader but when I saw the status indicating "Invalid Binary" then I realized no it hasn't been uploaded yet. I tried the most to figure out what could be the possible reason for this but unsuccessful. Please if anyone could help me out. nay answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This generally occurs when you don't code sign your application properly. You can find all information regarding this on your iTunes Connect account. Apple explains it step by step.

If you did that and are still getting the Invalid Binary status, then may be you need to re-download your certificates and update your provisioning profiles through XCode. Furthermore re-check that your schemes are correctly configured.

This link might help you as well:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011375-CH1-SW1

Answer (score 0):

when you see invalid binary on itunes connect, check your email, sometimes apple send you email with details about the problem.